# What would you need from a mobile usability testing service?

Tags: web-app, mobile, usability-testing

I'm thinking of launching a service similar to usertesting.com or trymyui for mobile website and apps.

Developers submit their app or website along with testing scenarios. Scenarios would be something like "You want to book a hotel room for next weekend at Waikiki"

Testers go through the scenarios while narrating their actions and thoughts. For example "Ok, so I'm going to enter 'Waikiki' in the search box and tap the search button".

The result would be a video of the phone screen, with the audio of the tester speaking.

Developers and UX designers, what else would you need from such a service?

Comment: How would you like to solve screen capturing? (I mean video clips?)

Comment: Recent versions of Android allow users to take screenshot without root access. Frame rate may be slow for now, but I'm confident it will be sufficient at the beginning - and that we can improve it later on.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get feedback on the content in the appstore, e.g. Is the description good, is the screenshots good. Is the app placed in the right category. Is the icon good.